# Using nginx with redis to read a key value pair

Tags: nginx, redis

I'm new with working on nginx and redis,Unable to connect a redis from nginx to read a redis key value

i see most of the documents for redis refer to old modules which are no more active on nginx

please help with a simple example for this

Answer (score 4):

I am using openresty with redis to read a key value pair.
Here is my conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

  #GET http://localhost/get?key=key
  location /get {
      default_type "text/plain";
        content_by_lua_block {
        local redis_info = {
            host = "127.0.0.1",
            port = 6379, 
            db = 0
        }
        local redis = require "resty.redis"
        local red = redis:new()
        red:set_timeout(1000)

        local ok, err = red:connect(redis_info.host, redis_info.port)
        if not ok then
            ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
            return
        end
        ok, err = red:select(redis_info.db)

        local value = red:get(ngx.var.arg_key)
        ngx.say(value)
    }
  }

  #SET http://localhost/set?key=key&val=value
  location /set {
      default_type "text/plain";
      set_unescape_uri $key $arg_key;
      set_unescape_uri $val $arg_val;
      redis2_query set $key $val;
      redis2_pass 127.0.0.1:6379;
  }
}
```

You can do the same thing with nginx, [please look at the document here.](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis)